# Yosys: Variable initial value to flip-flop at reset

Tags: yosys

I am trying to assign an initial value to the FF at reset. The initial value is an input to the circuit. In the cell library I added the following FF:

```
cell (DFF){
    area    : 0;
    ff(IQ,IQN){
        next_state  : "D";
        clocked_on  : "CLK";
        clear   : "I'*RST";
        preset  : "I*RST";
        clear_preset_var1   : L;
    }
    pin(CLK){
        direction   : input;
        capacitance : 0;
        clock   : true;
    }
    pin(RST){
        direction   : input;
        capacitance : 0;
    }
    pin(D){
        direction   : input;
        capacitance : 0;
        timing() {
          related_pin   : "CLK";
        }
    }
    pin(I){
        direction   : input;
        capacitance : 0;
    }
    pin(Q){
        direction   : output;
        function    : "IQ";
        timing() {
          related_pin   : "CLK";
          timing_type   : falling_edge;
        }
        timing() {
            related_pin : "RST";
            timing_type : clear;
            timing_sense    : positive_unate;
        }
        timing() {
            related_pin : "I";
            timing_type : clear;
            timing_sense    : negative_unate;
        }
        timing() {
            related_pin : "RST";
            timing_type : preset;
            timing_sense    : positive_unate;
        }
        timing() {
            related_pin : "I";
            timing_type : preset;
            timing_sense    : positive_unate;
        }
    }
}
```

The part of the Verilog code that I am trying to synthesize to this FF is

```
    always@(posedge clk or posedge rst)
    if(rst) begin 
        e_reg <= e_input;
    end
    else begin 
        e_reg <= e_shift;
    end
```

However, when I run the synthesis, it uses one of the built-in FFs from the Yosys library (`$_DFFSR_PPP_`) ignoring the one from the user-defined cell library. If I include one of the set-reset (SR) FFs in the user-defined library, like the following, that is picked up by Yosys.

```
cell(DFF) {
area: 0;
ff("IQ", "IQN") { clocked_on: CLK;
              next_state: D;
                  preset: I;
                   clear: RST; }
pin(CLK) { direction: input;
             clock: true; }
pin(D) { direction: input; }
pin(Q) { direction: output;
          function: "IQ"; }
pin(I) { direction: input; }
pin(RST) { direction: input; }
}
```

The earlier one works with Synopsys DC, but not with Yosys. It seems that the equations in `clear` or `preset` are not being picked up by Yosys.

In there any way to make it work? Am I missing something?

EDIT: I am adding a complete example in case anyone wants to run this.

**acc.v**

```
module acc #(parameter N = 1)( 
    input clk,
    input rst,
    input [N-1:0] a,
    input [N-1:0] b,
    output [N-1:0] o
);

    logic [N-1:0] o_reg;

    assign o = o_reg & a;

    always@(posedge clk or posedge rst) begin
        if(rst) o_reg <= b;
        else o_reg <= o;
    end 

endmodule
```

**asic_cell_yosys.lib**

```
library(demo) {
    cell(IV) {
        area: 1;
        pin(A) { direction: input; }
        pin(Z) { direction: output; function: "A'"; }
    }
    cell(AND) {
        area: 1;
        pin(A) { direction: input; }
        pin(B) { direction: input; }
        pin(Z) { direction: output; function: "(A&B)"; }
    }   
    cell(NAND) {
        area: 1;
        pin(A) { direction: input; }
        pin(B) { direction: input; }
        pin(Z) { direction: output; function: "(A&B)'"; }
    }
    cell(DFFSR) {
        area: 4;
        ff("IQ", "IQN"){clocked_on: C;
                        next_state: D;
                        preset: S;
                        clear: R; }
        pin(C) { direction: input;
                     clock: true; }
        pin(D) { direction: input; }
        pin(Q) { direction: output;
                  function: "IQ"; }
        pin(S) { direction: input; }
        pin(R) { direction: input; }
    }
}
```

**acc.tcl**

```
yosys -import
read_verilog -sv acc.sv
hierarchy -check -top acc 
procs; opt; flatten; opt; 
techmap; opt;
dfflibmap -liberty asic_cell_yosys.lib
abc -liberty asic_cell_yosys.lib -script +map; 
opt; clean; opt;
opt_clean -purge
write_verilog -noattr -noexpr -nohex acc_syn.v
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yosys' `dfflibmap` doesn't support expressions such as this for clear or preset in a Liberty file.

However, you could use the `techmap` command with a custom-made map rule to map `$_DFFSR_PPP_` to your own flipflop - similar to how we do FPGA techmapping in Yosys.

As an example of this. Create `dffsr_map.v`:

```
module $_DFFSR_PPP_(input C, S, R, D, output Q);
    DFFSR _TECHMAP_REPLACE_ (.CLK(C), .RST(S | R), .I(S), .D(D), .Q(Q));    
endmodule
```

and add `techmap -map dffsr_map.v -map +/techmap.v` after `dfflibmap`

Comment: Apologies for re-opening this after so long. Could you point me to any tutorial or example code that will help me understand the steps of using `techmap`?

Comment: I have edited the post to provide a complete example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example. It works now. However, there is still one small redundancy. The input to the `I` port is `b&rst`. Since the `DFF` only reads the `I` port when `rst` is high, this AND operation is redundant. I think the reason for this is that abc does not know about this property of the `DFF` specification. Is it possible to get rid of this AND gate? (The current output is good enough anyway).